# How to specify datatype and contentType in $http requests in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, request

I'd don't find on the internet how can I pass datatype and contentType to a shortcut request in AngularJS.

Exemple :

```
$http.get('url',{
                 headers:{'header1':'value'}
})
```

Second question : Can I send the header with this kind of code ?

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Api.getToken());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a content type like this, but for this you also need to specify data in the request also

```
 return $http({
               method: 'POST',
               //withCredentials:true,
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
               data: data,
               url: yourUrlHere
             });
```

data can be an empty string but with if you are not adding data it will not set the content-type

For short post method you can do it like this

```
 $http.post('/someUrl', data, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: yes but how could I do it with shortcut methods? Like $http.get

Comment: get method do not need content type, becuase you will not submit any data with get

Comment: Sorry then with $http.post :D

Comment: i have updated the answer you need to add options in third parameter of the post function